# How can I setup a deadline_timer in this environment?

Tags: c++, boost, timer, boost-asio

I am a bit lost in a construct of libraries, which I have to tangle together. I need help to indtroduce some timers into this construct.

I have the following:

- *com.cpp* which has `main` and includes *com.hpp*
- *com.hpp* which includes a *host.h* and needed boost includes and defines a class *comClient*
- *host.c* with included *host.h*
- *wrapper.cpp* with included *com.hpp* and some needed boost includes

Now, my *com.cpp* is creating a *comClient* and uses it for asynch communication on the com-port. Using `boost::asio::serial_port` and `boost::asio::io_service`.

I need to work with some timers, in order to catch when a paket needed too long to transmit.

When creating an instance of *comClient*, the paket-timer should be initialised.

Using `asynch_read_some` in a private function of *comClient*, I call a private handler of *comClient*, then this handler calls a function of *host.c*, which calls to the *wrapper.cpp* a function to restart the timer.

This is the function to init the timer:

```
//wrapper.cpp
void    IniPacketTimer(void *pCHandle){

    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(25));
    t.async_wait(&hostOnTimeout(pCHandle));
    io.run();
}
```

This would be the command chain in short:

```
//comClient.cpp
main{
  comClient cc();
}
//comClient.hpp
class comClient(boost::asio::io_service& io_service){
  comClient(){
   hostInit();
   aread();
  }
  private:
    aread( call aread_done)
    areaddone(call hostNewData())
}

//host.c
hostInit(){ 
   IniPacketTimer()
}
hostNewData(){
  resetTimer
}

//wrapper.cpp
resetTimer(){
  t.expires_from_now
}
```

**Questions:**

How can I provide an asynchronous timer, which does not affect the asynch read/write operations on my serial port, but triggers execution of a function when the deadline is hit?

Should I use the already existing `io_service` or is it ok, if I just create another?

Why do I get an error C2102 '&' expects L-Value for my line `t.async_wait`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is not clear and since you don't post real code it is quite hard to guess what your problem is.
Especially your threading is not clear but for asio very important.

Below is an example that will compile but not run. I hope it gives you an hint on how to proceed.
It will open a serial port and a timer. Whenever the timer expires it will start a new one. It is a stripped version of code I used some time ago so maybe it will help you.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <vector>


class SerialCommunication
{
    public:
    SerialCommunication(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, const std::string& serialPort)
        : m_io_service(io_service)
        , m_serialPort(m_io_service)
        , m_timeoutTimer(m_io_service, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5))
    {
        configureSerialPort(serialPort);
    }

    void configureSerialPort(const std::string& serialPort)
    {
        if(m_serialPort.is_open())
        {
            m_serialPort.close();
            m_timeoutTimer.cancel();
        }
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        m_serialPort.open(serialPort, ec);
        if(m_serialPort.is_open())
        {
            // start Timer
            m_timeoutTimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&SerialCommunication::TimerExpired, this, _1));
            header_sync();
        }
    }

    void header_sync()
    {
        m_serialPort.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(&m_header.back(), 1),
            boost::bind(&SerialCommunication::header_sync_complete, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void header_sync_complete(
        const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        // stripped
        read_payload(&m_payload[0], 0);
    }


    void read_payload(uint8_t* buffer, uint8_t length)
    {
        m_serialPort.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, length),
            boost::bind(&SerialCommunication::payload_read_complete, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void payload_read_complete(
        const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        // stripped
        // timer cancel and reset
        m_timeoutTimer.cancel();
        m_timeoutTimer.expires_at(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time() +
                            boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5));
        m_timeoutTimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&SerialCommunication::TimerExpired, this, _1));
        memset(&m_header[0], 0, 3);
        header_sync();
    }

    void TimerExpired(const boost::system::error_code& e)
    {
        m_timeoutTimer.expires_at(m_timeoutTimer.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(5));
        m_timeoutTimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&SerialCommunication::TimerExpired, this, _1));
    }

    boost::asio::io_service& m_io_service;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer m_timeoutTimer;
    boost::asio::serial_port m_serialPort;
    std::vector<uint8_t> m_header;
    std::vector<uint8_t> m_payload;
};



int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    SerialCommunication cc(io_service, "/dev/ttyS0");

    io_service.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, if the problem is still somewhat unclear. There is a lot of code to it. I hoped for an example as you gave, which seems to have quite the right parts. Now I can learn and adapt from it. This will take a bit - but many thanks for this code!

Comment: Hey, thank to you and some other posts, I finally got my timer somewhat to work - just not quite as expected. Here is my followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089110/lost-in-threads-how-can-i-extend-this-example-correctly. Thanks again for your help.